# Manipulate Windows layout, size and position from forreign code

Tags: windows, layout, position, screen, manipulate

I would like to change the layout, size and position of a window programaticaly. Is that possible?

The problem:
I use Chrome on a dual screen system in combination with chrome remote desktop (homeoffice). Chrome can't do a fullscreen mode on a dual screen. Always fullscreen's on the primary screen only. I'd like to code a little helper app that catches the windows handle of this chrome instance and sets size, position and removes the title and the control buttons. I'd like to mimic a full screen on the dual screen system. Any hints are appreciated.

TIA Ole

Comment: In which language do you wish to code this?

Comment: preferebly in VB.NET but any common language is fine